# Shield ui grid how to find the rowIndex by sui-updated-marker

Tags: jquery, grid, shieldui

I am trying to get the **rowIndex** of the recently updated cell. 
You can find out my approach below :

```
 getCustomEditorValue: function (e) {
                e.value = $("#qntyBox").val();
                if (!isNaN(e.value)) {
                    console.log(e.target.contentTable.find('.sui-updated-marker').get(0).rowIndex);
                }
            }
```

but it shows me *undefined* in the console output.

But

```
console.log(e.target.contentTable.find('.sui-updated-marker'));
```

gives me

```
Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object, context: undefined, selector: ".sui-updated-marker" }
```

Any help would be appreciable. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change the

```
e.target.contentTable.find('.sui-updated-marker').get(0).rowIndex;
```

with

```
e.target.contentTable.find(".sui-editable-cell").get(0).parentNode.rowIndex;
```

Comment: Really appreciate your support. :)